# How can I have two nodes of different content types update to each other?

Tags: nodes

I have two different content types(A & B), and I want to be able to have a field in content type A that is a select list of all the nodes from content type B, and then I want to have a field in content type B that is a select list of all the nodes from content type A. 
Is there a way that I can have those two fields update each other?

Ex: in node 'Atest' from content type A in the select list field I select the 'Btest' node from content type B, and then if I edit 'Btest' in it's select list field I can see 'Atest' already selected. (showing that 'Atest' has it selected)

Is that possible? if so, what would be the beat way to go about setting that relationship up?

Comment: What do you mean by "update each other"? You want to change options on node edit page? Or you want to change content of actual nodes?

Comment: I want to change the actual content of the nodes. I want to have a node reference select list in each content type that when edited in a node of one type will update the selected nodes' node reference select list in the other content type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try [Corresponding node references](https://www.drupal.org/project/cnr).

I used this to sync up Events and Venues on one of my sites, and whenever I switch a venue for an event it automatically changes the node reference on the other node, so I only have to change the node reference once, instead of twice. Keeps things tidy, works with multiple.

Comment: As a note [CER](https://www.drupal.org/project/cer) should be used since development has swapped over to there now.

Comment: Although I have yet to be able to get the CER module to with without errors